# mongoid query - calling the size method produces an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-query

When I execute this query:

```
User.where(:comments.size => 10)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `size' for :comments:Symbol
```

But according to the documentation here:

> http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html

This should be possible.  So, why the error?

Note: 'comments' is separate collection from User with a 'has_and_belongs_to_many' relationship.

I am using mongoid 3.0.0 and bson_ext 1.6.1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if User embeds Comments but not when you *relate* User to Comments. It works for embedding because of the $size operator (although, this is not a super efficient query to perform. Better to cache the size in a separate field).

Answer (score 0):

Use `with_size`, not `size`, with Mongoid 3. It will translate to the MongoDB `$size` operator.

> `Queryable#with_size`: Add `$size` selection. Matches documents who's array field has the exact size of the provided value. This is named `with_size` not to conflict with Ruby's `Enumerable#size` or `Symbol#size`." (from the [Origin Selection documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html))